# Can't get Apache & Django to talk

Tags: python, django, apache, mongodb, centos

So I have this Django/Angular project that I was thrown on and I'm having trouble getting it setup on a new server. I installed apache/python/pip/django and all the needed reqs and at this point I'm trying to get Django to talk to the MongoDB server.

**EDIT:** The project is using Django as the AppServer and Apache/mod_wsgi as the web server with AngularJS as the client/front end part.

**UNIX Environment** CentOS 7, SELinux=yes

Just for testing, I've set no authentication on the MongoDB end for the database/collection.

Here's part of my settings.py file:

```
# Django settings for my_proj project.
from mongoengine import connect
connect('CoreRubrics',host='<url>',port=27017)
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
#DATABASES = {
 #   'default': {
  #     'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
   #    'NAME': 'CoreRubrics',
    #   'HOST': '<url>'
 #   }
#}
```

this is the error I'm getting.

```
    [Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.195577 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593] mod_wsgi (pid=27781): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/CoreRubrics/DjangoBackend/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.195677 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.195722 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196110 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     self.load_middleware()
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196154 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 43, in load_middleware
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196405 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196442 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196607 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196670 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196712 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196826 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196953 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.196997 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.197123 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     __import__(name)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.197165 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/var/www/CoreRubrics/DjangoBackend/my_proj/settings.py", line 3, in <module>
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198018 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     connect('CoreRubrics',host='<url>',port=27017)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198059 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 164, in connect
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198206 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     return get_connection(alias)
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198237 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198271 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593]     raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\\n%s" % (alias, e))
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198312 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593] ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
[Thu Apr 09 16:30:07.198321 2015] [:error] [pid 27781] [client 172.16.75.12:49593] [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Since it is saying permission denied AND there's no authentication, I can only assume there's a file permissions error somewhere?

Comment: Your title and tags refer to Apache, but I can't see anything related to Apache in the question itself.

Comment: Ah sorry. I'm using mod_wsgi/Apache in front of Django. I'll put that in the question.

Comment: But really you should take Apache out of the equation anyway. In development, you should use Django's built-in dev server.

Comment: I'll give that a shot (in dev) and see how it goes.

Comment: Under Apache, on a system which uses SELinux, then there will be restrictions on making certain outgoing network connections. You need to set up SELinux to allow the connections from Apache. Add to your question what Linux OS you are using and whether SELinux is enabled.

Comment: Added

CentOS 7, SELinux=yes

Comment: I had this error once before, for me it was permissions error on the filesystem - can you change the owner of the mongo data directory to the same owner of the  webserver? If it is a remote server, is the connecting host allowed to connect per iptables/firewall rules?